# Master-slave replication in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I meet with a problem in the process of setting master to slave one-way replicate system. When I change the setting on master machine, it looks fine. But after I change the setting on slave. The following error message shows up when I try to get into MySQL on master server.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I guess that the problem occurs maybe because I don't change bind address of servers on `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. So I try again and change bind addresses of both servers. Master and slave server seem to be connected for a while since slave server replicated what master server did. But after a while, the error message `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` shows up again, first on master server, then on slave. I am trying to fix this problem by restarting servers, but failed.

The following is what I have done so far:

```
arp -a    //find ip of master and slave server
```

get into [mysqld]:

```
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

add:

```
for [master]

    server-id=1

    log-bin=mysql-bin

    change bind address to ip address;

for [slave]

    server-id=2

    replicate-wild-do-table=test.%  //only replicate data of database named test

    change bind address to ip address;
```

in mysql

```
for [master]

    create user 'repl'@'%' identified by 'slavepassword';

    grant replication slave on *.* to 'repl'@'%';

for [slave]

    change master to

    master_host='master server's ip',

    master_user='repl',

    master_password='slavepassword',

    master_log_file='mysql-bin.000001', // get from show master status

    master_log_pos=1358;                // get from show master status

    start slave;

    show slave status\G;

    show processlist;
```

I do restart master server after changing its setting in the process, but since the error message shows up, restarting failed.

Comment: why do you change the **bind address** try 0.0.0.0 or * for testing. you can also try to reach the master from client via mysql client like **$ mysql -h IP -u  repl -p slavepassword**

Comment: When I try to get into mysql with "mysql -h IP -u repl -p slavepassword," it prompts “Enter password:” to require root password for the remote machine, which I don't have. I have only the password of one of the client for the remote machine. Also, 0.0.0.0 doesn't work. I guess there may be something there blocks the connection like firewall?

Comment: sorry there is no space between -p and the password like **$ mysql -h IP -u repl -pslavepassword**